# Scrapy and possibilities available

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, data-extraction

I’m looking into web scraping /crawling possibilities and have been reading up on the Scrapy program. I was wondering if anyone knows if it’s possible to input instructions into the script so that once it’s visited the url it can then choose pre-selected dates from a calendar on the website. ?
End result is for this to be used for price comparisons on sites such as Trivago. I’m hoping I can get the program to select certain criteria such as dates once on the website like a human would.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory for a website like Trivago you can use the URL to set the dates you want to query but you will need to research user agents and proxies because otherwise your IP will get blacklisted really fast.